# Cannot call method 'create' of undefined chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

when i finish my chrome extension i find an error it is:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined chrome-extension://dpfgkakomehcgdcnigflmkcfngeaamlc/js/background.js:46
```

injectScript startLiveReload init

i use it is this

> mainfest.json "background": {
>       "scripts": ["js/background.js"]   }

and background.js like

```
var readMenuItemId = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "阅读模式",
  "type" : "normal",
  contexts : [ "selection" ],
  documentUrlPatterns: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "onclick" : genericOnClick
});
```

i do not know where is wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add permission `contextMenus` in manifest file in order to use this object:

```
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
],
```